# $A$ is an injective linear map s.t. $A=CB$ can $A$ be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an injective linear transformation from $ \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ B: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ and $C: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $A=CB$, $ p\neq n$. Is A invertible?

I am not sure of the solution. According to me $A$ is invertible since it is injective and the dimensions of the vector spaces are equal hence it is onto as well. But I am not sure what role does the fact $A=CB$ plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{2}$ and $C: \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R$ be defined buy $B(x)=(x,x)$ and $C(x,y)=x$ Then $A=CB$ is the identity function on $\mathbb R$ which is invertible.  So $A$ can be invertible.

Taking $B=0$ or $C=0$ we see  that $A$ is not always invertible.

Comment: This is a specific example. I am trying to find a general proof?

Comment: See my edit. @FaqirChand

Answer (score 0):

Consider $B:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $B(x)=(x,0)$ and $C:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $C(x,y)=x$.